# CXF issue with cookies using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cxf, siteminder

Recently i've faced strange issue with cookies being sent to my backend server (which is using CXF 3.1.2 for handling HTTP requests), it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie is malformed :
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.CookieHeaderProvider.fromString(CookieHeaderProvider.java:66) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.CookieHeaderProvider.fromString(CookieHeaderProvider.java:26) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie.valueOf(Cookie.java:126) ~[javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.HttpHeadersImpl.getCookies(HttpHeadersImpl.java:117) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.AbstractRequestContextImpl.getCookies(AbstractRequestContextImpl.java:59) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at com.acmecorp.acmeproject.whitelist.filter.AuthenticationInFilter.filter(AuthenticationInFilter.java:34) ~[AuthenticationInFilter.class:na]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.runContainerRequestFilters(JAXRSUtils.java:1636) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
```

This happens occasionally when i use Chrome or Opera, but this wasn't reproduced in Firefox or IE.
In CXF logs i've found next HTTP headers being sent to server:

> Headers: {Accept=[application/json, text/plain, */*],
>   accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, lzma],
>   Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.8], Cookie=[BlueStripe.PVN=300d00000051;
>   APP_USER="test_user1"; ; SMSESSION=(omitted)] }

The issue is in double semicolon in headers with space between them. CXF treats it as cookie which have no name and no value and throws an exception.

This issue may be related to Siteminder SMSESSION cookie which expires every minute or so.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the answer? As I said, it is not possible to answer completely without seeing the client code

Comment: Pedrofb, i highly appreciate your help. Will try to dig into this issue and give response asap. Thanks.

Comment: I've found that this issue may be related to Siteminder which we are using for implement SSO. It adds SMSESSION cookie to request and change it every minute. And this exception occurs only in this time interval, when Siteminder should update a SMSESSION cookie value (i submit HTTP request with old cookie value, it intercepts request and change cookie, but leave blank value '' which causes CXF to crash)

Answer (score 2):

A valid `Cookie:` header according with [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) should be

```
 Cookie: name=value *(; name=value)
```

One or more `name=value` pair separated by semicolon and space `;` . Your cookie is not valid because the third entry is void.

In server side, CXF [CookieHeaderProvider.fromString(cookie)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/3.1.1/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/CookieHeaderProvider.java) throws an `IllegalArgumentException` because name/value is null. This is not a CXF bug because the cookie does not meet the specification

I have not found any related bugs in [Chrome issue list](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list), so I suspect is a client issue

Next step is to determine where is beign included the blank cookie `;`

1. Debug the client code before call to see the current set of cookies
2. Inspect the http request headers and check `Cookie:` value

It would be helpful if you post the client code and the debugger results